# sequelize querying by association - nested includes?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sequelize.js

Here is my account Model:

```
    module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        accountPkey: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'account_pkey'
        },
        accountName: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'account_name'
        },
        imagePkey: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            field: 'image_pkey'
        }
    },
    associations: function() {
        Account.hasMany(Privilege, {
            as: 'Privileges',
            foreignKey: 'account_pkey'
        });

        Account.hasMany(AccountContact, {
            as: 'Contacts',
            foreignKey: 'account_pkey'
        });
    },
    options: {
        tableName: 'v_account',
        timestamps: false,
        classMethods: {
            whereUserIs(user_pkey, privileges) {
                return Account.findAll({
                    include: [{
                        model: Privilege,
                        where: {
                            'Privilege.privilege_type_name': {
                                $in: privileges
                            },
                            'Privilege.user_pkey': {
                                $eq: user_pkey
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                });
            }
        },
        instanceMethods: {},
        hooks: {}
    }
};
```

In my whereUserIs class method I am trying to return all accounts for which there exists a privilege which has the user_pkey and has any of the privileges passed in.

Please assume that the Privilege model has account_type_name and user_pkey properties. Is my syntax correct?

Edit: I am actually using this sails hook to load sequelize: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-sequelize

Second Edit: 
Here is a more complicated query: I would like to find all users which have a privelege on any of the accounts that were queried above:

```
User.findAll({
        include: [
            {
                model: Privilege,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: Account,
                        include: [{
                            model: Privelege,
                            where: {
                                'Privilege.privilege_type_name': {
                                    $in: privileges
                                },
                                'Privilege.user_pkey': {
                                    $eq: user_pkey
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    })
```

Does this second one make sense?

In both of these queries, will I get a list of entities (i.e. accounts or users) or will they be nested results (of all the includes)? How can I ensure that my lists of accounts and users are unique/distinct?